# Time for App aproval on Android

Tags: android

I'm wondering when i can expect a app to go thourgh the reviewing process and going into the android market, because I know that apps in the iphone market take like a day to a month, is it the same for the android?

Comment: could someone please tell me why this was downvoted so much?

Comment: Maybe because the answer could have been found easily at developer.android.com.  I looked at the other two question you posted as well and one other could have been answered with a quick Google search.  A lot of developers like to read about the research you tried on your own before you posted the question.  Try to add this info along with your question to show that you attempted to answer the question for yourself.  But I think 5 down votes is a little too much. It will only discourage a person, especially if no one leaves a comment why it was down-voted.  Good luck and your app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not have an app reviewal process. Your app will be uploaded immediately to the market when you submit it. It may how ever take a day or two to actually show up in search results.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Android Market, Google’s App Store, Will Not Require Approval For Applications](http://gizmodo.com/5043178/android-market-googles-app-store-will-not-require-approval-for-applications) for the answer to your question. It says:

> The Android Dev Blog today released some shots and details on the Android Market—the Android version of the iPhone's App Store. Stressing that it's a "market" (free, open, etc) rather than a "store," the Google folks have decided to not require an approval process for devs to have their applications listed, unlike Apple's mysterious black box of approval that even the developers still don't fully understand. Which is great news for Android devs, but could be quite a handful for Google.

You can also read [the FAQ](http://source.android.com/faqs.html) for all common Android questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reviewing process for Android Market. You may read the guide for publishing apps on Android Market.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Here it says,

> To publish your application on Android Market, you first need to register with the service using a Google account and agree to the terms of service. Once you are registered, you can upload your application to the service whenever you want, update it as many times as you want, and then publish it when you are ready. Once published, users can see your application, download it, and rate it.